# How can i bind value in element if i'm getting true or false ?

Tags: angularjs, data-binding

if I want to bind value in Html which is true or false. how can I display this value?

**Code:**

```
<li ng-if="display"><a ng-click="logout();" ><span class="icon mail">
</span>Logout</a></li>
<li ng-if="!display"><a href="#/login"><span class="icon mail">
</span>Login/Signup</a></li>
<li>{{$scope.display}}</li> // i want to print it here.
```

display value is true or false how can I print it? is it possible?

Comment: just remove the `$scope`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add $scope while printing it in html.
You can just bind like this.

```
<input type="text" ng-bind="display">
<li>{{display}}</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one may it helps

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="">

Keep HTML: 
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="myVar" ng-init="myVar = true">

<div ng-if="myVar">
<h1>Welcome</h1>
<p>Welcome to my home.</p>
<hr>
</div>
<p style="font-size:40px">{{myVar}}</p>

<p>The DIV element will be removed when the checkbox is not checked.</p>
<p>The DIV element will return, if you check the checkbox.</p>

</body>
</html>
```